# Free java swing datepicker

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, open-source

Is there any  free  datepicker exist for java in swing. I look through the following pickers such as jdatepicker jxdatepicker and Jcalendar. But all are licensed under BSD, LGPL and LGPL respectively.

Comment: Why do you say that BSD and LGPL aren't open source?

Comment: If I take open source library under LGPL licence and when I integrate it in my project,and i sell it in the market then I have to distribute my code to open source community If i don't change any library code then also i have to distribute my code...right

Comment: Open Source means the code is available for anyone to see. Do you mean that you want free code that can be made proprietary legally?

Comment: yea..I want the free code to create the date picker in java swing.

Comment: It seems like you do not completely understand how open source libraries' licences affects your work's license. Including open source library components doesn't necessarily mean you have to open source your code as well.

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of it you are looking for *free code* that can *legally be taken closed-source*, NOT specifically open source code.

**Open source** means just that - the source is open. It doesn't explicitly mean it can't be made closed source. The licence of the software specifies what can be done with the software in question. The GPL, for example, requires that derivative code must be open source.

As it happens, the **LGPL licence** - also known as the "lesser" GPL - is one of the licences that allows code under its licence to be released commercially without requiring that its derivatives are made open source as well. Similarly, the **BSD licence** also [permits closed-sourced derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#Proprietary_software_licenses_compatibility)

More reading:

- [Permissive Licences](http://opensource.org/faq#permissive)
- [GPL and LGPL open source licensing restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114045/gpl-and-lgpl-open-source-licensing-restrictions)
- [SmashingMag on OSS Licences](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/24/a-short-guide-to-open-source-and-similar-licenses/)